# Wordpress : woocommerce action hook to run before payment gateway redirect

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am newbie to Wordpress and  I want to run a function before payment gateway redirection in woo commerce.

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'initiate_order', 10, 1);

function initiate_order($order_id) {
    include('woocommerce/includes/emails/class-wc-email-admin-initiate-order.php');
    $email = new WC_Email_Admin_Initiate_Order();
    $email->trigger($order_id->id);
}
```

How can I initiate a mail to admin about the order before payment gateway redirection?

Comment: $order_id is not an object.

Answer (score 1):

I think these hooks will help you

```
  add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_process', 'initiate_order' , 10, 1 );
    function initiate_order($order_id){
        include( 'woocommerce/includes/emails/class-wc-email-admin-initiate-order.php');
        $email = new WC_Email_Admin_Initiate_Order();
        $email->trigger($order_id->id);
    }
```

1. http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_before_checkout_process/
2. http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_checkout_process/

Comment: This worked for me, thank you so much.
What I was trying to achieve is to change the selected currency before it redirects to payment gateway because my store have multiple currency options but the payment gateway only accepts one currency otherwise it throws error.

Answer (score -1):

If you want an order id as parameter to your action hook callback function you can use `woocommerce_thankyou` hook.

Comment: That hook is called at the end when it's redirected from the payment gateway. OP wants something BEFORE sending it to the payment gateway